# R long to wide format factor levels as binary variables and dates

Tags: r, format, reshape, dcast, spread

I want to make a long to a wide format and use the factor Levels as binary variables. This means, if the factor Level is existing at least once, then there should be a 1 in the variable. Otherwise a 0. In addition, I want the dates as variable values date.1, date.2,...

What I have is the following

```
data_sample <- data.frame(
  PatID  = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  date   = c("2016-12-14", "2017-02-04", "NA", "NA", "2012-27-03", "2012-04-21", "2010-02-03", "2011-03-05", "2014-08-25"),
  status = c("COPD", "CPOD", "NA", "NA", "Cardio", "CPOD", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cerebro")
)
```

What I want is:

```
PatID  COPD Cardio Cerebro date.COPD.1 date.COPD.2 date.Cardio.1  date.Cardio.2  date.Cerebro.1
1        1    0       0    2016-12-14  2017-02-04     NA               NA          NA
2        0    1       0      NA           NA        2012-03-27         NA          NA 
3        1    1       1    2012-04-21     NA        2010-02-03    2011-03-05      2014-08-25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few step to take but this should give you your desired output.

Note however that there seems to be a typo in the input data: I assume you meant `"COPD"` instead of `"CPOD"` because this is what you expected output tells me.

The first step is to make the string `"NA"` an explicit missing value, i.e. `NA`.

```
data_sample[data_sample == "NA"] <- NA
```

Now use `data.table::dcast` for the reshaping.

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(data_sample)

# create id column
data_sample[, id := rowid(status), by = PatID]
dt1 <- dcast(data_sample[!is.na(date)], PatID ~ status, fun.aggregate = function(x) +any(x))
dt2 <- dcast(data_sample[!is.na(date)], PatID ~ paste0("date_", status) + id, value.var = "date")
```

Finally join both data.tables

```
out <- dt1[dt2, on = 'PatID']
out
#  PatID Cardio Cerebro COPD date_COPD_1 date_COPD_2 date_Cardio_1 date_Cardio_2 date_Cerebro_1
#1:     1      0       0    1  2016-12-14  2017-02-04          <NA>          <NA>           <NA>
#2:     2      1       0    0        <NA>        <NA>    2012-27-03          <NA>           <NA>
#3:     3      1       1    1  2012-04-21        <NA>    2010-02-03    2011-03-05     2014-08-25
```

**data**

```
data_sample <- data.frame(
  PatID   = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  date = c("2016-12-14", "2017-02-04", "NA", "NA", "2012-27-03", "2012-04-21", "2010-02-03", "2011-03-05", "2014-08-25"),
  status =c("COPD", "COPD", "NA", "NA", "Cardio", "COPD", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cerebro"))
```